# Parshat Ki Tisa on Shabbat Shekalim

Tags: calendar, torah-reading, parashat-ki-tisa, four-parshiot

According to my Artscroll Chumash, it appears that parshat Ki Tisa can not be the scheduled Shabbat reading on Shabbat Shekalim (I assume this because the potential maftir and haftarah readings listed on page 515 include only the regular reading and the reading in the case of Parshat Parah). I assume that this is a certainty now that we have a fixed calendar. But I wonder if it was ever possible for Ki Tisa to coincide with Shabbat Shekalim.

If so, would there be a maftir for Shekalim (which is normally from the beginning of Ki Tisa) or would we have discharged our Shekalim obligation through the regular Torah reading of the exact same portion?

Comment: It's not possible because Shekalim is, by definition, the Shabbos before the last RC Adar (or on RC if RC is Shabbos). Since Pesach can only be a Sunday, Tuesday, Thursday, or Shabbos, RC Nissan must be as well. Since Adar always has 29 days, RC Adar must be a Shabbos, Monday, Wednesday, or Friday, which means there are always seven weeks between Pesach and Shekalim. In a non-leap year, Pesach always follows Parshas Tzav, so seven weeks will place Shekalim on Parshas Mishpatim every non-leap year. (con't)

Comment: (con't) Since in a leap year Pesach always follows Parshas Metzora or Acharei, seven weeks earlier (which includes Metzora/Acharei) will always be Vayakhel or Pekudei. So in any event, it's impossible with the rules of our calendar for Shekalim to fall out on Ki Sisa, though if the Kri'as HaTorah cycle was shifted by just one week it would be possible in certain leap years.

Comment: @DonielF Could happen nowadays if shul was closed by snowstorm the week of ki tisa where next week is vayaqhel-shklaim? (or if they forgot to read shklaim on truma and hold https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1494&st=&pgnum=234 it has tashlumin the next week)

Comment: @DonielF Any snowstorms in the weather near you for this week?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is discussed in the Bavli ([Megillah 30a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=30&format=pdf)) and while one opinion recommends reading from [Shemot 30:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9891#v=17) to the end of the Parsha, and then reading Shekalim at the end, the conclusion is in accordance with the opinion that we read the whole Parsha and then go back and read the Shekalim section again.